# how to write url to Laravel 9 correctly?

Tags: laravel, url

How to open a page in a browser without a category? Now all pages are opened (/category/post), but how to do this (/post)? Here is how I wrote

web.php

```
Route::get('{post_slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController::class, 'viewsPost']);
```

FrontendController.php

```
public function viewsPost(string $post_slug) {
$post = Post::where('status','0')->get();
return view('frontend.post.views', compact('post'));
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work!

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what "doesn't work"? what are you doing, what do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController::class, 'viewsPost']);
```

If you want to return all the posts with 0 status you can just use this code. You don't need parameter in there like {post_slug}.

If you want to get a specific post you can use like

```
    Route::get('/posts/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController::class, 'viewsPost']);
```

{slug} or whatever you want to name it your parameter.

But in your controller function, I see that you don't need to use parameter.